# STM32CubeIDE: What is the correct method to import drivers and middleware from example projects to the current project?

Tags: eclipse, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32h7

When we are importing an example project to the STM32CubeIDE, it probably uses `.cproject` and `.project` files present in the project directory to import required drivers and middleware. For example, here's a list of source files for an example project import into the IDE:

[image]

How can I automatically add the set of sources part of `Middleware` and `Drivers` folder above to a new project's `.project` and `.cproject` files, so that they are properly added to the build configuration?

Comment: Are you using STM32CubeMX?  With STM32CubeMX, you can select the drivers and middleware that you want to include and it will generate the project for you.

Comment: @kkrambo I'm not sure, I'm using the the standard STM32CubeIDE, is STM32CubeMX part of the IDE? Thanks!